# Is there a german equivalent for 'prepper'?

Tags: single-word-request

I am wondering if there is a germain equivalent for a *prepper*. dict.leo.org didn't "know" this word. Would the average ordinary german person understand the word *prepper*?

Comment: please explain what a *prepper* is. I am german nativespeaker and do not know all exotic english words.

Comment: Do you mean what used to be called preppies, kind of the opposite of punkers? Guys who dress stylishly and all that? The English word will be used just like with punkers.

Comment: I just noticed the same question (although for English). http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/63461/is-prepper-a-word-that-an-average-english-speaking-person-understands

Comment: Like a Selbstversorger but with far more of a military gear fetish... kind of a hybrid Selbstversorger and Mall Ninja...

Comment: I would say ` Privatvorsorger`. I have a friend who "preps" tobacco and honey for the world end.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: Ein Prepper präpariert sich für den Weltuntergang/den 3. Weltkrieg/die Zombieapokalypse o.ä. in dem er Vorräte, Energieträger und Waffen bunkert, evtl. Windräder u. Solarmodule kauft.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a german website about preppers: http://prepper.de/prepper

They do not translate the word. "Prepper" is used as a foreign word in german, but most people will not know what is meant with it.

Comment: Ich denke, das hat sich heutzutage geändert. Es gibt immerhin eine Netflixserie, die Prepper heißt.

Comment: Und was ist Nextflix? Das sind diese Fernbusse, oder?

Answer (score 9):

I don't know if I'm an average ordinary German person, but `prepper` was unknown to me.

I found [this definition](http://www.prepper.org/):

> Prepper (noun): An individual or group that prepares or makes preparations in advance of, or prior to, any change in normal circumstances or lifestyle without significant reliance on other persons (i.e., being self-reliant), or without substantial assistance from outside resources (govt., etc.) in order to minimize the effects of that change on their current lifestyle.

In German it could be [`Selbstversorger`](http://dict.leo.org/ende?lp=ende&lang=de&searchLoc=0&cmpType=relaxed&sectHdr=on&spellToler=&search=selbstversorger), but I think that's more general (a self-supporter).

http://prepper.de/prepper contains also no translation, only explanation of the word. They introduce `prepper` as a new word. So I think there is no translation, German needs a new (foreign) word for it. Prepper seems to become a loanword.

---

I had another idea: `Autarkist`. This word doesn't exist in German - but I think it can be understood by native speakers (at least I would). It is a derivasion of `Autarkie` (autarky) or `autark sein`.

Comment: Bohnen, blaue Bohnen und Gold. Die Bohnen sind für den Hunger, die blauen Bohnen gegen die Nachbarn, das Gold... wird sich schon 'ne Verwendung finden für.

Comment: I like the `Autarkist` suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

**Prepper** is a relatively new word in English as well. Therefore it is of little suprise that there is no German equivalent. Given recent language history I bet this will not come up but instead **Prepper** will stay an English loanword until it has become out of fashion again.

Closest to the main characterisics of a [Prepper](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepper), and in case we desperately need to translate this word to a German-only expression we may take

> Überlebenskünstler

Comment: I am not sure if `Überlebenskünstler` conveys the meaning of prepper (as I understand it). knut's `Selbstversorger` seems to be the better alternative. I see an `Überlebenskünstler` as someone who survives in spite not preparing for anything as opposed to a `prepper` who wants to survive and prepare for that goeal.

Comment: Well, prepper is a form of survivalism. I would not recommend to translate *prepper* but we may need to explain it because it is not well known. *Selbstversorger* also is something else as knut already ponted out. A prepper may be sort of a mixture from *Selbstversorger* and *Überlebenskünstler*.

Comment: Wie wärs mit `Verschiebe-nicht-auf-morgen-was-du-heute-kannst-Besorger`? (Stupid Microsoft Word spellcheck puts a squiggly red line underneath.)

Comment: I'm not sure what people think it they hear about a "prepper". In my mind preppers tend to be suspicious of the government and preparing mostly for a state of "without rule of law". This is a thing which is quite rare in Germany (good luck stockpiling guns :3) and the term "Überlebenskünstler" describes more of an Bear Grylls or Rüdiger Nehberg type of person.
"Selbstversorger" on the other hand do not *prepare* for something, but are already living a certain lifestyle.

Comment: Ein Überlebenskünstler ist jmd., der sich bereits mehrfach aus aussichtslosen Situationen herausgearbeitet hat, das passt überhaupt nicht. Der Prepper bereitet sich nur vor - am Ende hat er vergessen einen Dosenöffner zu bunkern und verhungert neben seinen Vorräten.

Comment: @0x6d64: When I hear "Selbstversorger", I think of someone who produces their own food, possibly also their own clothes. The mental image I have is someone who wants to live ecologically and who would maybe rather support a peace movement than arming themselves. Google Image illustrates the difference quite well: "Selbstversorger" yields images of gardens, gardening equipment, and happy-looking people amidst their plants, whereas "prepper" yields images of canned food and people with camouflage clothing and rifles.

Answer (score 0):

There is a English netflix Serie called "Preppers". The German description is:  "Überlebenskünstler, die sich auf unterschiedliche Katastrophenszenarien und den Untergang der Zivilisation vorbereiten"